# How to continuously update video from images that keep coming in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, video-streaming, video-capture

I am working on a robotics project in which a robot creates images in .pgm format (not camera images) continuously which I'm converting to .jpeg and saving to a directory. However, this directory keeps updating as more images keep getting added while I want to convert these images continuously in a video. I can already create a video from the images saved in one instance but what I want is to update the video continuously as a single file (streaming onto a URL) while images keep getting saved. Here is my code but it doesn't work in parallel for images as well as for videos. Anyone can help?

```html
from PIL import Image
import os, glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os.path import isfile, join

# remove .yaml files
directory = "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/ros_map/map_pgms"
files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)

filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".yaml")]

for file in filtered_files:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    os.remove(path_to_file)


def batch_image(in_dir, out_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        print(out_dir, 'is not existed.')
        os.mkdir(out_dir)

    if not os.path.exists(in_dir):
        print(in_dir, 'is not existed.')
        return -1
    count = 0
    for files in glob.glob(in_dir + '/*'):
        filepath, filename = os.path.split(files)

        out_file = filename[0:9] + '.jpg'
        # print(filepath,',',filename, ',', out_file)
        im = Image.open(files)
        new_path = os.path.join(out_dir, out_file)
        print(count, ',', new_path)
        count = count + 1
        im.save(os.path.join(out_dir, out_file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    batch_image('/home/user/catkin_ws/src/ros_map/map_pgms', './batch')

# convert the .jpgs to video
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('./batch/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width, height)
    img_array.append(img)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```